# Django child model's Meta not available in a @classmethod

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to write a check for django abstract base model that verifies some facts about the inner `Meta` of a derived class. As per [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/checks/#field-model-manager-and-database-checks) the check is a `@classmethod`. The problem is that in the method the `cls` parameter is the correct type of the derived class (`Child1` or `Child2`), but its `Meta` is the `Base.Meta` and not the `Meta` of the appropriate child class.

How can I access the inner `Meta` of a child model in a base model's `@classmethod`?

I've tried both with a simple `Meta` class (no base class - `Child1` below) and with one that derives from the base class' `Meta` (`Child2`) - as per https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#meta-inheritance

```py
from django.db import models


class Mixin:
    @classmethod
    def method(cls):
        print(f"{cls=}, {cls.Meta=}")
        print([attr for attr in dir(cls.Meta) if not attr.startswith("__")])

class Base(Mixin, models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    age = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Child1(Base):
    city = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "city_table"
        verbose_name = "12345"


class Child2(Base):
    city = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta(Base.Meta):
        db_table = "other_city_table"
        verbose_name_plural = "qwerty"

Child1.method()
Child2.method()
```

In both cases the output is:

```
cls=<class 'mnbvc.models.Child1'>, cls.Meta=<class 'mnbvc.models.Base.Meta'>
['abstract']
cls=<class 'mnbvc.models.Child2'>, cls.Meta=<class 'mnbvc.models.Base.Meta'>
['abstract']
```

While I want `cls.Meta` to be the Meta of the child class.

Answer (score 0):

Django uses metaclasses in order to preprocess a model class before the object of a class (not the instance of the class) is fully initialized.

Please look at the `django.db.models.base.ModelBase` metaclass source code for more information.

Basically all `Meta` classes except the ones on abstract models are stripped out. Their information are stored in Model's `_meta` attribute.